# eBay API MinPrice works, but MaxPrice doesn't

Tags: javascript, ebay-api

When interacting with eBay's API using the URL format, the `MinPrice` item filter works, but the `MaxPrice` does not. My guess is that it has something to do with the enumeration, but I don't completely understand how that works, and I'm not sure what to change it to. Code is below.

```
<script src=http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*APP ID GOES HERE*&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=6&outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)=New&itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value=201.00&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(0).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(1).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(1).value=200.00&itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter.name=ListingType&itemFilter.value=FixedPrice&itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD&keywords=iphone%205%2016gb%20unlocked>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both maxPrice and minPrice filter names are assigned to the same itemFilter element

`itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).name=MinPrice`

which is incorrect you should specify each filter on a different itemFilter element, i.e.

`itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice`

Also you have `itemFilter.name=ListingType` which is not valid either, the name property is on an element of itemFilter not on the itemFilter list itself, it should be `itemFilter(3).name=ListingType`

The correct url would look something like:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*APP ID GOES HERE*&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=6&outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)=New&itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value=201.00&itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value=200.00&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value=FixedPrice&keywords=iphone%205%2016gb%20unlocked
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, thanks! Would you happen to know how I could make it show higher resolution thumbnails?

Comment: You can get larger thumbnails by using the outputSelector field in your request. Pass the value GalleryInfo and you will get back three thumbnails that are large, medium and small. You can pass other values into the field to get back images that are 800x800 in size if they exist. See the following link for more information.

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html#Request.outputSelector

Comment: I passed `outputSelector=GalleryInfo` into the url, but that doesn't seem to work, and their tutorial isn't very clear on the matter. Do I need to append some sort of itemFilter after the GalleryInfo?

Comment: `&outputSelector=PictureURLSuperSize`

Comment: `http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=x&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=rc%20boat&AvailableItemsOnly=true&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)=New&itemFilter(0).name=ListingType&itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice&PaymentMethod=PayPal&itemFilter(0).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(0).value(0)=CN&paginationInput.pageNumber=1&categoryId=87480&outputSelector=PictureURLSuperSize&itemFilter(4).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(4).value=100.00`